# Как мне получить имя java файла из кода?

Tags: java

Нужно получить имя собственного файла из кода, ну и желательно полный путь. Как это реализовать?

Comment: @blueTUZZ_01, уточните ваш вопрос, укажите в вопросе, путь до какого файла вы хотите получить? `.java` или `.class` или `.jar`?

Comment: @Vadik .jar и .java т.к собираюсь компилировать после тестов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот к примеру :

```
    return new File(MyClass.class
.getProtectionDomain()
.getCodeSource().getLocation()
        .toURI()).getPath();
```

MyClass ток на свой изменить.

А забыл, что  изначально нужно имя, а не путь. Ну файл называют так же как и сам класс поэтому

```
MyClass.сlass.getSimpleName()
```

- выведет имя файла без расширения.

Либо исходя из выше изложенного

```
    return new File(MyClass.class
.getProtectionDomain()
.getCodeSource().getLocation()
.toURI()).getName();
```